# In Suse when I run `id` for my user it does not reflect what I get back when querying a Name Service Switch Database for group

Tags: linux, unix, nis

I have a Linux environment that uses NIS and VAS (OneIdentity) for authentication/authorization. I am finding there is a mismatch or cache happening somewhere and I am unable to pinpoint where it is happening. When I log in as my user I and run `id` I will get a list of groups that I am a part of. Right now it lists that I am in

```
GroupA
GroupB
```

The nsswitch file has a group entry that looks like this

```
group: files nis
```

So it should read from files and then from NIS. All of the group information resides in NIS. *FYI There is **no initgroups entry** in nsswitch*

Now if I check the group db from the group name service switch database using

```
getent group -s files | grep {MyId}
```

It will show I am part of no groups (This is expected as I want all groups to roll through NIS)

However, if I query the NIS db using

```
getent group -s nis | grep {MyId}
```

It will show that I am part of all these groups

```
GroupA
GroupB
GroupC
GroupD
```

Here is where it starts to get interesting. If I check the initgroups db (Which I only semi-understand how this works) using

```
getent initgroups {MyId} -s files
```

It only shows my user id (This is expected as I want all groups to roll through NIS)

Now I will check what initgroups my user is part of in NIS

```
getent initgroups {MyId} -s nis
```

This matches what I see when I run `id` above

```
GroupA
GroupB
```

This to me seems like a mismatch. ***Wouldn't I expect to see the same results when querying NIS for groups and the initgroups?*** When I query groups it looks like I should be put in a lot more groups but I'm not for some reason.

I am also running nscd locally and have reloaded and restarted that service and no changes were noticed. I have also rebooted the machine with no luck either. ***Does anyone have a suggestion on what to check out next?***